# Parenthesis in string

Tags: string, excel, vba, formula, parentheses

I'm trying to fill in a range of formulas but can't seem to find the proper way of getting parentheses in there.

For example;

```
Cells(1,1).Value = "=SUMPRODUCT("
```

will return a runtime error because of the (.
I tried a whole bunch of stuff, including;

```
Cells(1,1).Value = "=SUMPRODUCT" & Chr(40)

Cells(1,1).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT("

Cells(1,1).Value = "=SUMPRODUCT" & "("
```

etc but they all seem incorrect.

What mistake am I making and how do I get this right?

EDIT: response to first responses

1) I'm not talking about the solving of the sumproduct, I'm talking about entering the formula itself, from vba into excel.

2) if I set

```
Cells(1,1).Value = "=SUMPRODUCT"
```

Then it works fine: my formula becomes =SUMPRODUCT
But if I add the opening parenthesis

```
Cells(1,1).Value = "=SUMPRODUCT("
```

I get Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error
when running the sub.

EDIT2: It seems the sumproduct formula has to be closed correctly with ")" in order not to get the runtime error. I guess I was wrongly assuming the Cells.Value was merely setting a string which would not be tested in any way.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT *of what*? In Excel it is an error to write  `=SUMPRODUCT(` all by itself in A1.  Also -- the ampersand (&) is superfluous since both of the strings on either side of it are string literals.

Comment: It needs to be the SUMPRODUCT of something, you will need to do Cells(1,1).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(" & your parameters & ")" I am assuming your parameters are dynamic, if they are static then you don't need the double qoute and And in the middle Cells(1,1).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(your parameters)"

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question -- there is no need to treat parenthesis different from any other character in string literals. Presumably you were trying to combine these strings with something else to make a larger expression. The problem is undoubtedly with what you were trying to do with these strings, not with the syntax of the string literals. What were you trying to do and what was the actual error message?

In response to your subsequent edits, the reason why VBA accepted `=SUMPRODUCT` but not `=SUMPRODUCT(` as a formula you could put in a cell is because the former can be interpreted as a user-defined name but the latter is just an incomplete formula. I can see now how you thought that the problem was with how to put parentheses in a string, but the error code you got (1004) means that it was Excel rather than VBA per se which was raising the error.

Also, if you *do* want the literal string "=SUMPRODUCT(" to display as text in a cell, you can do so in at least two ways:

1) Change the cell's format to display as text:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Selection.Value = "=SUMPRODUCT("
```

2) Use a single quote mark at the start of the string. This correspond to how you enter literal strings in a spreadsheet cell:

```
Selection.Value = "'=SUMPRODUCT("
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: But it does. The *original* question (before edits made it over twice as long) is what I was responding to. That was about the proper VBA syntax for including parentheses in strings. The answer is that in VBA parentheses can be treated like any other character. The rest of my answer is also appropriate in the sense that *anybody* who searches SO for VBA syntax for parentheses in strings is mistaken about the source of their difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was flummoxed, because a string entry that had worked up to that point now ran into runtime errors, and it was traced back to adding a paranthesis into the string.  The answer was that one of the cells had not been formatted as a string prior to running the macro.